# Cypress How to assert that no navigation happend?

Tags: cypress

I have a button that depending on the circumstances should or should not initiate navigation. How do I assert in a cypress test that no navigation was initiated?
I tried:

```
cy.get('button').click();
cy.wait(2000);
cy.url.should('contain', 'original/url');
```

This works, but it takes 2 seconds to wait for a potential navigation. Also, if by any chance the navigation was initiated, but it did not finish in 2 seconds, this test shows a false positive. Is there a better way?

Comment: Why does navigation occur or not occur? Is there a network request that can be intercepted and waited on?

Comment: @agoff The navigation occur or not based on some local state. The navigation does not necessarily produces a network request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot perform a ***negative*** assertion in less time than to longest expected time.

If you think about `cy.wait(<some-time-period>)` vs `cy.get(..., {timeout: <some-time-period>})`, the timeout is only better than the wait because the event occurs earlier than `<some-time-period>` and the test moves on.

But if you want to be sure that the event ***has not occurred*** in that time period, you must wait the full time period.

---

Your second issue ***Also, if by any chance the navigation was initiated, but it did not finish in 2 seconds*** is not an issue, because Cypress always waits for navigation to finish before executing the next command.

---

Finally, it is a pretty flaky test if the navigation can occur or not occur.

You mention **some state** controls the navigation, in that case you should set up the state and expect the navigation to occur.

Comment: I need to test both cases. It is easy to test the case when the navigation occurs. In this test the navigation does not occur. I wrote that the navigation can occur or not occur to indicate the necessity of the test.